# Term describing where someone is from or what nationality they are?

Tags: single-word-requests, obscure-terms

Is there a term for the word that describes where a person is from or what nationality they are?  For example, someone from America is an American, and someone from Finland is a Finn.  Is there are term for the words *American* and *Finn* that denotes that they mean "someone from  a particular place"?  I could have sworn I stumbled upon such a word years ago, but I cannot for the life of me remember it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words you are looking for are *gentilic* or *demonym*.  Not especially obscure, either.

Comment: Demonym, that is the word!  Thank you.

And sorry for mis-tagging it.

Comment: @tchrist Well, Tom, "demonym" is not in the Merriam-Webster Unabridged, thus it's obscure at least for them:-). Surely perfect, though, as 'the name used for the people who live in a particular country, state, or other locality'. However, "gentilic" doesn't seem to be its synonym, as per M-W U Definitions.

Comment: @Marius See [*gentilic*](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/gentilic). As for *demonym*, this is readily available in the OED, not to mention on next to every Wikipedia page about applicable places. It is also obvious from its Greek roots.

Comment: @tchrist. Ah, thanks. M-W U only has "a name with gentilic value"  on the noun side. At your link I see the synonym.